# Interpretation about the exchange of energy among oscillators

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, nonlinear-dynamics, celestial-mechanics

I'm studying Hamiltonian system and in particular the role of frequencies in these systems. What I want to understand is about the physic interpretation of some definition.

Considerer a Hamiltonian system of the form
$$ \sum_{l=1,...,n} \dfrac{y_l^2}{2} + V(x) $$
where $(x,y)$ are canonical variables and $V$ is the potential. Assume that $V$ has a minimum at the origin. Then by standar theory there exist a canonical variables (normal modes) $(\bar p, \bar q)$ in wich the Hamiltonian takes the form
$$\sum_{l=1,...,n} \dfrac{\bar p_l^2 + \omega_l ^2 \bar q_l^2}{2} + P(\bar q)$$
Thus if one neglect the function $P$ one can consider the system as a system of $n$ independent harmonic oscillators with frequencies $w_l$.

I can interpret all using a chain of $N$ masses attached with springs. In this way I can image the dynamic of the whole system as the superposition of normal mode, and I can visualize the motion of normal modes and what the frequencies represent in the motion.

Now define non resonant frequencies: given the vector of frequencies $\omega=(\omega_1,..., \omega_n)$ the frequencies are nonresonant if $<\omega,k>\neq 0 $ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$.

My question is: what does it change in the motion of masses when one consider non resonant frequencies and the completely resonant one ( for example, fixed $\omega$,  $\omega_l= \omega$ for every $l$)?
In which sense there is "an exchange of energy among the oscillators in the resonant case and how do the masses actually move?

Comment: Any interaction has to come from the term $P$. What are the assumptions there? $P$ is free of constant and linear terms by normalization and equilibrium. By construction of the coordinate choice it should also be free of quadratic terms. Are there cubic terms? Is it completely constructed of 4th degree terms?

Comment: Isn't possible to have a generic visualization? However, let be cubic terms.